# Does RTK initialState update the components?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

In Redux tool kit there is an option to set initial state. So we can create a reducer to set initial state.

My problem is, will it update all of the components which use that state?

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: {name: 'stack'},
  reducers: {
      reset: () => initalState,
  },
})
```

I use name state in component A and then call reset reducer from component B. Even if the state is updated, component A will not re-render. Why is that? I wonder if this `initialState` function is not updating relevant content.

Comment: Do provide a minimal reproducible issue. Add your relevant components where you are using the reducer

Comment: `initalState ` doesn't appear to be defined anywhere. Please [edit] to provide a complete and accurate [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, including the UI component code that is selecting and updating the state, and clarify in better detail what the issue is, including your exact reproduction steps to produce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do ensure that the `reducer` is created the right way. In your given code, the **reset reducer** has not been created correctly.

Here is how you should do it:

```js
const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: { name: 'stack' },
  reducers: {
    resetState: () => {
     const defaultState = { name: 'default' }
     return defaultState;
    }
```

Also, do ensure you are **dispatching** this correctly:

```js
const ComponentB = () => {
  const name = useSelector(state => state.counter.name);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleReset = () => {
    dispatch(resetState());
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counter Name: {name}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleReset}>Reset Name</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This won't work. You can't reassign the `state` in a RTK slice reducer. This code also isn't changing the state to the `initialState` value. OP's reducer code is absolutely correct, assuming they have properly declared an `initialState` variable.